# Dreaded "ordinal not in range" when using UnicodeWriter -- files write/read cleanly otherwise

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, unicode

I'm trying to use the [UnicodeWriter example](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) given at the bottom in Python 2.7's documentation for the csv writer library but I am getting the infamous: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xb7' in position 53: ordinal not in range(128)` error as soon as I pass data to UnicodeWriter's writerow() that contains a diacritic.

I am able to write the data to a file without error like so:

```
ff = codecs.open(conf.settings.CSV_OUTPUT_DIR + '/' + filename, mode='w', encoding='utf-8')
ff.write(r)
```

where r is an index into a row in a cursor from an Oracle database result.  When I view the resulting file, the diacritics and other non-ASCII characters show up just fine.  However, when I switch to using UnicodeWriter like so:

```
ff = codecs.open(conf.settings.CSV_OUTPUT_DIR + '/' + filename, mode='w', encoding='utf-8')
writer = UnicodeWriter(ff)
writer.writerow(row)
```

(where row is simply a list I concatenated of all the strings* I retrieved from the cursor for that particular row) it fails with the error message I copied above.  How come I can write the data to disk (and read it fine) using write(), but I can't with UnicodeWriter?  What am I doing wrong?

*I hesitate to use the word string here because I think that has a specific meaning in Python 2.7 (that I don't understand very well).  I mean it in the general sense.

P.S. If it matters, my NLS_LANG envvar is set to .US7ASCII.  Also, please pardon any ignorance I have -- I'm new to working with Unicode and character encoding/decoding in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second example note that `UnicodeWriter` handles the encoding. In other words you needn't open the file with `codecs`, and in fact this is what is causing the exception.

Instead you can open the file normally. The `UnicodeWriter` class default encoding is UTF-8. So your code should look more like:

```
import os # for os.path.join(): a cross-platform solution to combining path elements
with open(os.path.join(conf.settings.CSV_OUTPUT_DIR, filename), 'wb') as fou:
    writer = UnicodeWriter(fou)
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works great now.  And thanks for the tip about combining path elements!

Comment: Cheers. Your question was written up quite well which made it easy to spot that one minor issue. Happy coding!